# angular ngclick of ngTouch: mouse click works right, while touch does not(Using iscroll5)

Tags: angularjs

Firstly I'm using angular 1.2.14,

In this case ng-click of ngTouch is used:

```
<section class="scroller-container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul id= "scroller">
      <li data-ng-repeat="competitor in competitors">
        <div class="competitor-title" data-ng-click="selectCompetitor(competitor)">
          <div class="title-name">
              <span>{{competitor.competitorTitle}}</span>
              <br>
              <span>{{competitor.competitorName}}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="landmark"></div>
          <div class="landmark-emphasis">
            <i class="icon-arrow-down-blue"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Then the controller:

```
app.controller('intelligenceController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){...}]);
```

In which:

```
  $scope.selectCompetitor = function(competitor) {...};
```

And I used ng-click-active, the document says:"This directive also sets the CSS class ng-click-active while the element is being held down (by a mouse click or touch) so you can restyle the depressed element if you wish."

So I click or touch the div, style changes. However touch doesn't trigger the method, while mouse click trigger the method.

In short, mouse click works right, while touch only change the style, why?

**Edit(old):** The problem is solved, using android webview it works all right. I tested my webapp on surface pro, the touch does not work ok.

**Edit** The root cause is you need to set iscoll option (click: true), otherwise in UIWebview and surface pro it will not work ok.

Answer (score 0):

did you add ngtouch in your module ?

```
var sellApp = angular.module('process', ['ngTouch']);
```

and also include it

```
        <script src="js/angular-touch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: can you show more code ? because from what you post, it must work, problem should come from somewhere else